# How to find all possible concatenation of characters in a table [ in a table ] in Lua

Tags: arrays, lua, concatenation

How can I find all possible concatenations of characters in a table [ in a table ] and display them as strings with new lines?

Example, I have a array of tables with characters:

```lua
c={
    {'1','2','3'},
    {'a','b','c'},
    {'A','B','C'}
}
```

I want to find all possible concatenations like

```
1aA
1aB
1aC
-- second table second character
1bA
1bB
1bC
-- second table third character
1cA
1cB
1cC
-- first table second character
2aA
2aB
2aC
-- and so on...
```

There could be many tables with however much characters. Appreciate the help!

EDIT:

I've found my answer here,

https://forum.cheatengine.org/viewtopic.php?p=5773931#5773931

Comment: I believe the word you are looking for is permutations, your permutations have some restrictions but, I believe if you do some searches with that term you will dig up what you are looking for.

Comment: Will concatenations always have the length 3 ?

Comment: No, there may be more or less. The one I gave is just an example. And they may also be more tables aswell.

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm assumes that there are always an equal number of values in each row, with that assumption we can say you have `(#c[1])^(#c)` values and use this information to flatten the tables.

```lua
c = {
    {'1','2','3'},
    {'a','b','c'},
    {'A','B','C'},
}
local columns = #c[1]
local rows = #c

for i = 0, (columns)^(rows) - 1 do
    local output = ""
    for k, v in ipairs(c) do
        output = output .. v[i % ((columns)^k) // ((columns)^(k - 1)) + 1]
    end
    print(output)
end
```

Output:

```
1aA
2aA
3aA
1bA
2bA
3bA
1cA
2cA
3cA
1aB
2aB
3aB
1bB
2bB
3bB
1cB
2cB
3cB
1aC
2aC
3aC
1bC
2bC
3bC
1cC
2cC
3cC
```